# Picking Shape Keras- ValueError: expected dense_1_input to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (13,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have made a neural network for a final project but when I run it, gives me "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)"  I am brand new to coding and very lost. Have attached the link for Colabs. Thank you:)

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcUuTVVDGwxHn2O5qqJk0wgiEf83MslN/view?usp=sharing][1]

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-prices

So I have changed the shape to multiple numbers and every time it tells me to change to 6, when I change to 6 it gives me other numbers. I also ran "print(X_train.shape)" which gave me "(16512, 6)"

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(6,), activation='relu'))
```

I would like the neural network to run and predict housing prices.

Comment: try to post some more code and do not add a picture, I cannot open it for example...

Comment: You should read the error messages very carefully, as the error in your question and the one in the title do not match, one talks about the input, the other about the target (the output). Both input and output shapes must match the one in the dataset.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see how to make a [MCVE].

Comment: Please do **not** post code in the comments - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Housing price prediction is a regression problem since the target label/output is a single (housing price) continuous value. Therefore, final Dense layer of your model should have only one unit/neuron with linear activation function whereas you have 2 unit with `sigmoid` activation. Furthermore, you should should compile your model with `mean_squared_error` loss function.

```
model.add(Dense(1))  # Default activation is Linear
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.05), loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Hope it will help.

It's recommended to scale your features to be in the same range as features are in different ranges. You may want to check out [Why, How and When to Scale your Features](https://medium.com/greyatom/why-how-and-when-to-scale-your-features-4b30ab09db5e).

Comment: Thank you so so so much!! it finally ran.. though now it doesn't seem to be working.. I thought I did scale it.

Comment: Epoch 50/50
 - 1s - loss: 56241543897.3416 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 56146462407.5932 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00                                                    58     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: Thanks @bit01 , I made the changes but can't figure out what to put instead of argmax. I tried looking up what Numpy function to use for linear regression but couldn't find it.

Comment: I also thought I did scale it with this code: from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()

X = sc.fit_transform(hous.drop('median_house_value', axis=1))
y = hous['median_house_value'].values

Comment: Since it's not a classification problem and output is a real number (continuous value) for each input you should not apply `argmax` on prediction. If you check the shape of `y_pred` that definitely should be `(no_of_test_sample, 1)` and you can access `y_pred` using index. For instance the predicted price for first test sample is `y_pred[0][0]`. You may drop the 2nd dimension of `y_pred` using `y_pred = np.squeeze(y_pred)` to make the shape same as `y_test` and then you can access the first prediction using `y_pred[0]`. Sorry, i missed `fit_transform`.

Comment: I made the changes to the code on google colabs but the model is still not outputting correctly.

Comment: Epoch 50/50
 - 0s - loss: 5394500843.5603 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 5624739660.4706 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-2243d1d0ef0a> in <module>()